# Extract data from HTML Table with mechanize

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, mechanize

First of all, here is the sample html table :

> ```
>  <tr>
>    <td><strong>Kangchenjunga </strong></td>
>    <td>8,586m<br /></td>
>    <td>28,169ft</td>
>    <td><div align="center">Nepal/India </div></td>
>    <td>1955; G. Band, J. Brown </td>
>  </tr>
> ```

The ARGV[0] will have the name of a mountain ( the first colomn) and the return value should be the last column, the people who climbed the mountain for the first time.

So I need to check if the whole rows first column is the ARGV[0], and if it is, then I should return the last column without the date.

```
require 'mechanize'
p=Mechanize.new.get('www.alpineascents.com/8000m-peaks.asp').body
if p.include?('<strong>'+ARGV[0])
   puts 'ok'
end
```

I've got the following, which prints "ok" if I have the ARGV[0] in the body of the html document.
How can I search for the last column of the same row, where the ARGV[0] is found?

EXAMPLE :

```
<tr>
 <td><strong>GIVE THIS AS A PARAMETER </strong></td>
 <td>SKIP THIS<br /></td>
 <td>SKIP THIS</td>
 <td><div align="center">SKIP THIS</div></td>
 <td>I WANT IT TO RETURN THIS</td>
</tr>
```

I'm really new to Ruby

Comment: did you look at Nokogiri gem for parsing your HTML (http://nokogiri.org/)?

Comment: Yes I did, but I don't really know how to use it.
I don't know how to set the search criteria, to get the row in the html table

Comment: I will post a mechanize solution for you. It uses nokogiri internally to parse HTML. It does offer some nice conveniences that you do not get with nokogiri. I am a big lover of mechanize and will hook you up in a quick minute.

Comment: Thank you Dan!
Please check the original post, I made an edit with some things I changed, and got working!

Comment: Hot damn gina I just got posted my solution to the problem to get you started with mechanize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More succint version relying more on the black magic of XPath :)

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.alpineascents.com/8000m-peaks.asp'))
last_td = doc./("//tr[td[strong[text()='#{ARGV[0]}']]]/td[5]")

puts last_td.text.gsub(/.*?;/, '').strip
```

Comment: The only problem is, that if the ARGV[0] has a space in it, it won't work!

Comment: Fixed the error when there is a space in the ARGV[0].
Instead of ARGV[0] I wrote ARGV.join(" "), so it joins two or more words into a string

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want (you will need to gem install nokogiri)

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.alpineascents.com/8000m-peaks.asp'))
rows = doc.search('//table')[6]./('tr')
rows.shift
rows.shift

rows.each do |row|
  if row.text.include? ARGV[0]
    puts row./('td')[4].text.gsub(/.*?;/, '').strip   
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! 
I was kinda curious about this whole nokogiri thing, and I found a blog post about this : 
"
- We pass in the path that we want to find. We want to look at any <tr> element that has a nested <td> element and a <a> element. The text nested in the <a> element should equal ‘AutomationUIGroup’. If that is true, we want to get the next <td> element’s text value.

“//tr[td/a = 'AutomationUIGroup']/td/text()”

I kinda want to do the same, find the text between the first <td> tags and then return one of the next ones.

Comment: Sure - I'll add that as another answer

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake that I see is that you are calling the following:

`p=Mechanize.new.get('www.alpineascents.com/8000m-peaks.asp').body`

Unfortunately grabbing the body from the mechanize object will just return all the body text as you would find in the DOCTYPE body block.

This information is quite annoying to parse through so I would recommend doing the following.
`p=Mechanize.new.get('http://www.alpineascents.com/8000m-peaks.asp')`

This will return a Mechanize#Page object which you an play with(http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html)

With that object we can simply perform a search which is nokogiris search by doing the following;

`elems = p.search('tr')`

this will return all the tr elements as a Nokogiri::XML::Element which we can use pretty cleanly to get the information that we want. Note that you may want to play around with all the stuff in IRB to figure out exactly what you need but the idea is should be clear from the following:

`elems.first.search('td').last.text` which will return the final td elements text from the first tr element we searched for before.

If you have any questions / want me to clarify feel free to ask away.

I have been hacking on things with mechanize for a long while now.

EDIT:

If you want to be able to look up the values this using some argument this is how I imagined you would solve the problem

```
values = {}
elems.each do |e|
  td = e.search('td')
  values[td.first.text] = td.last.text
end
```

When you have the values hash filled you can do the following:

if ARG[0] = "Everest"

then

`> values["Everest"]
 => "1953; Sir E. Hillary, T. Norgay"`

Comment: Thank you for this!
The only question : where can I add my ARGV[0] so I can search for the text of the first <td>?

Comment: I was thinking that the mechanize solution would build a hash for the values that you were looking for. I will edit my answer to include my thoughts on how you could do that easily and cleanly with the current structure that I have laid out